# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Guys I'm going crazy with this error. Iǘe already searched for it here and have a few answers but none of them worked with me. And to make me crasier is that this code:

```
_reloadInfo()async{

    Firestore reload = Firestore.instance;

    DocumentSnapshot orderStatus =
    await reload.collection("users")
        .document(_userId).get();

    Map<String, dynamic> status = orderStatus.data;
    setState(() {
      _orderStatus = status["order_status"];
    });

  }
```

Is working normally on another class. I just copied, because I want the same result in this one that is the same type of class (statefull) this error happens.

> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(24705): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly that `_userId` is an empty or null string.  Before calling Firstore APIs, you should verify that you have the correct strings for the document path that you need to access.  Add some debug logging to see for yourself, or use a debugger to step through your code to see what you're working with.

Comment: I printed the _userId and it’s loading fine. I’ve already put inside the same function that gets the uid and the same error happens even changing to a direct call that in my case is _loggedUser.uid and the same. The thing that makes me crazy is that this same code is working on another page normally.

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you know the string is being set properly.  Add a debug log statement just before the query that proves everything is work up until the point of the query.  As it stands now, your question does not have enough details.  I suggest also trying to hard code the string into the API to see if it works.

Comment: This is crazy. Now I put on build state and worked, but keeps calling many times, and it’s not what I want. I definitely don’t know why on initState doesn’t work. And about what you said, I’m a beginner and don’t know exactly what and how to debug or hardcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem, but not exactly the way I think it shoud be but I'll tell you.

I was putting this function:

```
_reloadInfo()async{

    Firestore reload = Firestore.instance;

    DocumentSnapshot orderStatus =
    await reload.collection("users")
        .document(_userId).get();

    Map<String, dynamic> status = orderStatus.data;
    setState(() {
      _orderStatus = status["order_status"];
    });

  }
```

To start on the initState right equall I did on my other page. And the result was that error.
Then I tried to start on the build and it worked, but kept calling many times, and the conclusion was this:

```
void _getOrderStatus()async{
    if(_orderStatus == false){
      DocumentSnapshot orderStatus =
      await db.collection("users")
          .document(_userId)
          .get();

      Map<String, dynamic> status = orderStatus.data;
      setState(() {
        _orderStatus = status["order_status"];
        _tableId = status["table_id"];
      });
    }
  }
```

Put inside an if, after got the result I wanted haha.

But I still want to know why it doesn't work on initState.